# Easiest way to move data to other database

Tags: php, python, sql, database, migration

I have two versions of my blog: the 1st is written in PHP and uses MySQL, but the 2nd, the new one, is written in Python and uses Postgres.

My goal is to move data from one to other. Table names and schema changes.

My idea was to make ORM models for old site, and, using loop, get data using ORM and put it in new database, because I have ORM models for my new site too.

It would look something like:

```
old_articles = OldArticle.objects.all()
for old_article in old_articles:
    new_article = NewArticle()
    new_article.title = old_article.name
    new_article.content = old_article.body
    new_article.save()
```

ORM would easy abstract differences between the databases and, in my opinion, this could actually work! Or no, are there better ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this migration will only be done once, I wouldn't go the ORM way. Exporting standards-compliant SQL dumps from MySQL is possible and the dumps could easily be imported into PostgreSQL. Once the data is in PostgreSQL, run your migration queries to make the scheme changes or use temporary 'import' tables and copy the data to the tables in the new scheme/lay-out.

Test all your migration queries and write a scenario containing all steps to take, which queries to run and in what order. Also include manual steps that need to be performed.

Once you're sure that the migration scenario is correct, and fully tested, put your old blog in 'maintainance mode' (sorry, we're offline, we'll be back soon) and do it for real!

Most important: test your scenario, validate the result and, take your time, you should never hurry these things!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of libraries to do this sort of thing.  I would stick to something that is already implemented and well tested. Here is a link to the postgres wiki that has a list of tools to do just this thing.

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL